# Active Thread vs Concurrent Threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image]I want 40 Active Threads, which are doing some kind of action... I have described my issue below

I am executing one of the test plans in which I am using jp@gc - Stepping thread group... In this, I have 40 concurrent users (this group will start)but when I execute this test... The ACTIVE threads are in different number (i.e less than 40).

How can I achieve 40 Concurrent and 40 Active threads?

[image: Active Threads over the time]

Comment: Provide us the "Stepping Thread Group" configuration of your test script.

Comment: Stepping thread group ... info provided .. please let me know .. if ur looking for more info??

Answer (score 3):

If you need 40 concurrent active threads for a specific period of time, I would suggest you use the [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/).

Here is an example:

**Ultimate thread group Configuration:**

[image]

Output of "**Active Threads over time**" Listener:

[image]

By using this, you can easily achieve **40 concurrent** users at any time period.